# Why is it in an infinite loop?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to capture the data from a json page, and store it in a database. I can currently get the artist and title from the json page. I am filling a array in my program with the values captured from data to avoid repeats. When run the for loop and get the values and put them in the Parsearray, an infinite loop starts. It does not end, a it's always being called. I know this because i see "called" being printed in the console multiple times and it does not stop. How do I fix this?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

        for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
            self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

            print(self.Parsearray)
            print("called")

        }
    })

    self.getSpotify()

}

 func getSpotify(){

    let searchTerm = "tgirish10"
    var endpoint = NSURL(string: "<api URL>")
    var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint!)


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(endpoint!) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let jsonData = data,
                let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as? NSDictionary,
                let recent = dict["recenttracks"] as? NSDictionary,
                let items = recent["track"] as? NSArray {
                    for item in items {
                        if let spotifytitle = item["name"] as? String {
                            print("title: \(spotifytitle)")
                            if let spotifyartist = item["artist"]!!["#text"] as? String{
                                print("artist: \(spotifyartist)")


                                let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
                                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                                    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                    var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                                    for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                                        self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

                                        print(self.Parsearray)
                                        print("called")
                                    }

                                    if self.Parsearray.contains(spotifytitle){
                                        print("already in db")

                                    }else{

                                        let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")
                                        objectPointer["title"] = spotifytitle
                                        objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                                        objectPointer["artist"] = spotifyartist
                                        objectPointer.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                                            if(error != nil){
                                                print(error)
                                            }else{

                                                print("saved")
                                            }
                                        })

                                    }

                                })


                            }
                        }

                    }
            }
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
            print(jsonError)
        }


    }
    task.resume()


}
```

Comment: Have you cleaned and run the code

Comment: Yes I have, it still does not print the called or the array.

Comment: I fixed it, but for some reason it's now in an infinite loop.

Comment: did you know the reason for this issue

Comment: Yes nothing was wrong with the code it was just the placement, but now there is an infinite loop.

Comment: You can try breakpoints to see where it goes wrong. The code is kinda complex, so cannot say what's wrong easily.

Comment: Doesn't look infinite, you're just making lots and lots of requests to the network so it'll take time to process and some may be failing and or queued up (not sure if parse limits the concurrent request count)

Comment: So instead I decided to query through in the view will appear, but I want the function to be called after the query is finished. Where would I place `self.getSpotify()`?

Comment: Don't use `for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1`but rather `for objectID in objectIDs`. Then you can directly use `objectID` instead of `objectIDs[i]`

Comment: You request the data from Spotify twice: once sync via `var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint!)` (which blocks until a response is received, and the results of which you don't actually use), and a second time async via `dataTaskWithURL`. Remove the sync call.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the issues in the comments above, the main problem is that your code does the following:

- get some data from Spotify
- for each track, get all `Pointer` objects from Parse
- for each of those objects, add title to `parseArray` (so after a while, the list will contain multiple copies of all titles)
- then check if title of the track is in this list

So the loop does not seem to be infinite, but you are unnecessarily adding a lot of data.

Two options:

- move the loading of the titles outside of the loop on tracks
- or use a `PFQuery` which only returns `Pointer` objects which match, and just check if the returned list is empty or not